# Android video saves as type "file" instead of video format

Tags: android, node.js, video, ffmpeg

So I have a website where I allow people to upload a video from their phone and send it to their friends.

Now `Iphone` works well because it is usually an `.mov` file. However when I attempt on my android (Samsung galaxy) I get FileType: file

Howere is an image from my filezilla as to what has been uploaded:

[image]

The highlighted are the files uploaded from the android device.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? and how I can make sure that it is a video? and/or convert it into a mp4 format.

Comment: I'm guessing it is because the files appear to have no extension.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard So how can i fix that? and make sure its an mp4 file?

Comment: I can't see your code, and I have no idea how you created these files, so I can't give any suggestion or than to simply rename them with the proper extension and see if that does what you want.